# PHP-FPM 8.0 Install

Tags: php, debian

Spun up new Azure web app and have it as PHP8.0 on apache running Debian 10. Wordpress is running on it and i'm trying to get php-fpm installed to increase performance a bit.

1. Updated my APT Repo (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded)
2. Trying to install PHP-FPM (sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid php-fpm htop)

But i get  Package 'php-fpm' has no installation candidate

Also tried putting in php8.0.3-fpm but couldn't find the package

Comment: Add [Ondrej Sury's PHP repository with this script](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt), then install php-fpm with `sudo apt install php8.0-fpm libapache2-mod-fcgid` and restart apache2.

Comment: you night want to use apt install php8-fpm

Comment: Tried both the suggestions, no luck :(

Package php8.0-fpm is not available, but is referred to by another package. (after doing Dijijay)

and for djdomi i get Unable to locate package php8-fpm

Comment: did you run apt update before installing?

Comment: I did up the update, but....i figured it out. Apparently when upgrading azure web app from PHP 7.4 to 8.0, it changes from Apache to Nginx with fpm preconfigured